# How to use GAE demos?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm new to GAE and want to learn from the demos in the demos-folder of the SDK. How can I import these demos into my eclipse workspace? I've tried file->import->existing project into workspace, without success. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new general project in eclipse
2. Drag and drop the demos
   into it as references (without copying the content, just linking to
   it)
3. Activate the ant view (under winow, views, other views)
4. open the folder of the demo you want to run and drag and drop the
   build.xml into the ant perspective
5. click on the run button 6-chose
   the runserver option in the ant perspective and run it

not fully integrated with eclipse but will probably do

Answer (score 0):

try new project with existing source

Comment: Where can I find that function?

Answer (score 0):

Get the proper plugins for eclipse. If you are using java, get google eclipse plugin [here](http://code.google.com/eclipse/)

For python you can get the pydev plugin  [here](http://pydev.org/)

Comment: I have the plugins! The question is how to use the samples in the demo-folder in the SDK.

Comment: Create a new appengine project in eclipse. And replace the src folder with the demo code in sdk.